# Is it necesarry to open fasts with dates?

Tags: sunnah, sawm, ramadan

Im confused, whether I should open my fasts with dates or will any other fruit suffice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assalamualaikum,
It is not obligatory to break the fast with dates but it is highly recommended by the Prophet.

Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) is quoted as saying: “When one of you is fasting, he should break his fast with dates; but if he cannot get any, then (he should break his fast) with water, for water is purifying” (Abu Dawood: 975).

So, it is your free choice but dates is the best choice for breaking the fast.

Hope this answers your question...